# What's faster: Creating a gradient programmatically using Quartz2D or just importing an image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, quartz-graphics

Let's assume the file space on the iphone isn't an issue, what would perform better? Would there be any noticeable speed/smoothness difference between the two?

Comment: what you will do with gradient ? can you describe your question

Comment: Right now, in my UITabBar buttons and my UITableView cells. But I could add them in other places as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whilst not specifically targeting gradients (*rather patterns*) [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2167/core-graphics-101-patterns) by Ray Wenderlich does have some basic information at the bottom with regards images vs. Core Graphics drawing.

TL;DR Core Graphics is seemingly quite a bit faster when used in this context.

For what it's worth, I do as much drawing as possible in my app using Core Graphics including such things as radial gradients and textured `UILabel`'s. As a developer with limited design skills I find I often get far better results drawing this way than fumbling about using something like Photoshop.

Another advantage with using Core Graphics is that you can change things on the fly with ease, such as animating a gradient, which would be incredibly expensive were you to do it solely with images.

Comment: Wanted to recomend the same article:)

Answer (score 1):

Importing an image hits the disk, so it's going to be marginally slower. After the image is rendered it doesn't matter where it came from because the result is cached. Unless you need to update the image and ask for a redraw, in which case, it depends on the complexity of the gradient vs displaying the already cached image, but the image is probably faster.

Comment: When the device is running low the first thing that gets hit is the cache.

Comment: The layer gets cached after being drawn, and never released before its owner. If you talk about the image cache, I would worry more about memory warnings and less about drawing vs images.

Comment: My point was that if you receive a low memory warning and as a result dispose of a view then the cache will also be cleared (*because of the low memory scenerio*). If you then have to recreate that view, a subsequent disk read is required to load the image meaning the most expensive operation could realistically happen more than once.